# Why is .reduce() requiring me to enter a starting value for the accumulator when using it to sum a specific key value pair in an object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I think I actually might have figured this out, just looking for confirmation to make sure I am really understanding this.

I was doing a practice exercise with this array

```
 const cards = [
    { id:4, name:'charmander', type:'fire', base_experience:62 },
    { id:7, name:'Squirtle', type:'water', base_experience:63 },
    { id:11, name:'Metapod', type:'bug', base_experience:72 },
    { id:12, name:'Butterfree', type:'flying', base_experience:178 },
    { id:25, name:'Pikachu', type:'electric', base_experience:112 },
    { id:39, name:'Jigglypuff', type:'normal', base_experience:95 },
    { id:94, name:'Gengar', type:'poison', base_experience:225 },
    { id:133, name:'Eevee', type:'normal', base_experience:65 },
]
```

and this reduce

```
    const totalScore = cards.reduce((acc, card) => {
        return acc + card.base_experience
    })
```

It kept returning a weird object sort of thing and concatenated strings instead of summed up numbers.... I THINK since I didn't provide a starting value for the accumulator, it was just using the first object as the accumulator and then trying to add a number to it and it just didn't work. Once I added the starting value like this.

```
    const totalScore = cards.reduce((acc, card) => {
        return acc + card.base_experience
    }, 0)
```

It worked fine. I was wondering if there would be a better way to do this. I tried this.

```
    const totalScore = cards.reduce((acc, card) => {
        return acc.base_experience + card.base_experience
    })
```

I pretty much knew it would fail since the second run through the acc would be whacky.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: "If no initialValue is supplied, the first element in the array will be used and skipped.", see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce). `{ id:4, name:'charmander', type:'fire', base_experience:62 }`, an object, won't be working as intended with the `+` operator.

Comment: You've already found the *better way* ...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#Parameters):

> initialValue: A value to use as the first argument to the first call of the callback. If no initialValue is supplied, the first element in the array will be used and skipped.

In your case, you have to add an initial value, since you deal with numbers. You can compact a bit more your code (since your return only one value):

```js
const cards = [
  {id: 4, name: "charmander", type: "fire", base_experience: 62},
  {id: 7, name: "Squirtle", type: "water", base_experience: 63},
  {id: 11, name: "Metapod", type: "bug", base_experience: 72},
  {id: 12, name: "Butterfree", type: "flying", base_experience: 178},
  {id: 25, name: "Pikachu", type: "electric", base_experience: 112},
  {id: 39, name: "Jigglypuff", type: "normal", base_experience: 95},
  {id: 94, name: "Gengar", type: "poison", base_experience: 225},
  {id: 133, name: "Eevee", type: "normal", base_experience: 65},
]

const totalScore = cards.reduce((acc, {base_experience}) =>
  acc + base_experience
, 0)

console.log(totalScore)
```

You can also map first `base_experience`, then do the sum:

```js
const cards = [
  {id: 4, name: "charmander", type: "fire", base_experience: 62},
  {id: 7, name: "Squirtle", type: "water", base_experience: 63},
  {id: 11, name: "Metapod", type: "bug", base_experience: 72},
  {id: 12, name: "Butterfree", type: "flying", base_experience: 178},
  {id: 25, name: "Pikachu", type: "electric", base_experience: 112},
  {id: 39, name: "Jigglypuff", type: "normal", base_experience: 95},
  {id: 94, name: "Gengar", type: "poison", base_experience: 225},
  {id: 133, name: "Eevee", type: "normal", base_experience: 65},
]

const totalScore = cards
  .map(c => c.base_experience)
  .reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)

console.log(totalScore)
```

The last one I can propose is with [sumBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#sumBy):

```js
const cards = [
  {id: 4, name: "charmander", type: "fire", base_experience: 62},
  {id: 7, name: "Squirtle", type: "water", base_experience: 63},
  {id: 11, name: "Metapod", type: "bug", base_experience: 72},
  {id: 12, name: "Butterfree", type: "flying", base_experience: 178},
  {id: 25, name: "Pikachu", type: "electric", base_experience: 112},
  {id: 39, name: "Jigglypuff", type: "normal", base_experience: 95},
  {id: 94, name: "Gengar", type: "poison", base_experience: 225},
  {id: 133, name: "Eevee", type: "normal", base_experience: 65},
]

const totalScore = _.sumBy(cards, "base_experience")

console.log(totalScore)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: So in that first example, you are destructuring base_experience out of the card right? I didn't know you could do that like that. And then doing an implicit return. That's good.

Comment: I also liked the other two options... Got a little happy with the return key there. Thanks!!!

Comment: Heh... I see your answer is good. When I've seen it has -2 there is something wrong with it. Weird... there is quite lot such ugly down-votes now a days.

Answer (score -2):

you can do something like that:

```js
const cards = [
    { id:4, name:'charmander', type:'fire', base_experience:62 },
    { id:7, name:'Squirtle', type:'water', base_experience:63 },
    { id:11, name:'Metapod', type:'bug', base_experience:72 },
    { id:12, name:'Butterfree', type:'flying', base_experience:178 },
    { id:25, name:'Pikachu', type:'electric', base_experience:112 },
    { id:39, name:'Jigglypuff', type:'normal', base_experience:95 },
    { id:94, name:'Gengar', type:'poison', base_experience:225 },
    { id:133, name:'Eevee', type:'normal', base_experience:65 },
]

const totalScore = cards
    .map(s => s.base_experience)
    .reduce((acc, exp) => acc + exp)
    
console.dir(totalScore)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Chaining them like that makes the reduce easier to understand. I read the several articles on reduce before I realized it was passing the whole first object in.

Comment: Why i was downwoted?